# no output from org-babel code using R

Tags: r, emacs, org-babel

Org 8.2.10
Emacs 24.5.1
OSX 10.10.3

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R    
1 + 2
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 3
```

but with

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R
  x <- rnorm(100)
  summary(x)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
```

"Code block produced no output"
and the *Messages* buffer contains:

```
Error reading results: (beginning-of-buffer)
Code block produced no output.
```

I am not sure why I don't see any output from the second example. It runs find in the R installation on my machine,

I'd be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add `:results output` to the header line, e.g.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :results output
  x <- rnorm(100)
  summary(x)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
:     Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
: -2.63500 -0.42370  0.02539  0.04136  0.48370  1.92000
```

Org [can capture results from code blocks in two different ways](http://orgmode.org/manual/results.html#results):

> The following options are mutually exclusive, and specify how the results should be collected from the code block.
>
> - `value` This is the default. The result is the value of the last statement in the code block. This header argument places the evaluation in functional mode. Note that in some languages, e.g., Python, use of this result type requires that a `return` statement be included in the body of the source code block. E.g., `:results value`.
> - `output` The result is the collection of everything printed to STDOUT during the execution of the code block. This header argument places the evaluation in scripting mode. E.g., `:results output`.

Since your first block returns a regular value it works without specifying anything for `:results`, using the default `value` setting.

Your second block [returns a value that must be explicitly printed](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/summary.html):

> The default method returns an object of class `c("summaryDefault", "table")` which has a specialized `print` method.

[R code that returns values with specialized `print` methods must be treated specially in Org](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-R.html#orgheadline7) (emphasis mine):

> If the source code block uses grid-based R graphics, e.g., the lattice and ggplot2 packages, then care must be taken either to print() the graphics object, specify `:results output`, or run the code in a `:session`. **This is because the graphics functions from lattice and ggplot2 return objects that must be explicitly printed to see them, using the print function.** This happens automatically when run interactively, e.g., `:session`, but when called inside another function, it does not. The way `:results value` is defined to operate, device and ggplot2 function calls are wrapped in a `main` function, and unless the object is specifically printed, no output is produced.

As mentioned, explicitly calling `print` and running the code in a `:session` are other possible solutions.

Comment: It's unclear to me as a non-Emacs user (but a fairly competent R user) why you think the second code segment should produce no value. The summary function with a numeric vector argument returns a structure with class "summaryDefault".

Comment: @BondedDust, you [appear to be correct](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/summary.html). I have little experience with R, but lots with Emacs, so my original answer was coloured by that. I've done a bit of research and updated my answer; hopefully this clarifies things.

Comment: Heh. "appear"? Only appear? I did look at the page before posting but more importantly and conclusively I executed `dput(summary(x))`.

Comment: @BondedDust, I didn't mean it grudgingly. I tend to avoid conclusive statements in areas where I'm not an expert. To be clear: based on the content of your comments and the documentation that they prompted me to review, you *are* correct :-).

Comment: Keep in mind the difference between **output** and **value**. If I remember correctly, Org-mode source blocks default to outputting values into the corresponding results bin. 

From my admittedly relatively limited understanding of R, the R REPL prints the output of all executed operations. This is, I believe, why `summary` could produce the desired output in the R REPL but not pipe said output accordingly when in an Org-mode source block unless the `result` type is explicitly set -- because `summary` isn't a **print** function per se.